# Unable to read BLE characteristic with Windows Bluetooth APIs

Tags: c#, bluetooth, win-universal-app, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a **Adafruit Bluefruit UART Friend** module (https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-the-adafruit-bluefruit-le-uart-friend/introduction) and i am trying to make an Universal Windows App from which i can read the bluetooth data. I followed the steps showed on the microsoft page and succesfully connected to the device but when trying to read the data from the specific RX characteristic, i get **System.ArgumentException** in console. I checked the flags on the characteristic and it looks like th READ flag return false, only the NOTIFY flag being true. Is it possible that I am not reading the right characteristic? I got the UUID from Adafruit site: https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-the-adafruit-bluefruit-le-uart-friend/uart-service Here is my C# code sample: `

```
public static async Task connectToAddress() {

      Guid guid = new Guid("6e400001b5a3f393e0a9e50e24dcca9e"); // Base UUID for UART service
      Guid charachID = new Guid("6e400003b5a3f393e0a9e50e24dcca9e"); // RX characteristic UUID

      deviceReference = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(_deviceAddress);
      GattDeviceServicesResult result = await deviceReference.GetGattServicesAsync();

      var characs = await result.Services.Single(s => s.Uuid == guid).GetCharacteristicsAsync();
      var charac = characs.Characteristics.Single(c => c.Uuid == charachID);

      GattCharacteristicProperties properties = charac.CharacteristicProperties;

      if (properties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Read))
            {
            Debug.Write("This characteristic supports reading from it.");
            }
      if (properties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Write))
            {
            Debug.Write("This characteristic supports writing.");
            }
      if (properties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Notify))
            {
            Debug.Write("This characteristic supports subscribing to notifications.");
            }

      GattReadResult data = await charac.ReadValueAsync();
      Debug.WriteLine("DATA: " + data.ToString());

      charac.ValueChanged += Characteristic_ValueChanged;

        }`
```

Comment: In your Debug. write you use the same lines for read and write("This characteristic supports reading from it.". Fix this first.

Comment: Thanks, but I still can't read from the characteristic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are reading data just after connecting, there might be nothing to read.

Your Bledevice is an UART Service, so i am sure it will send a Notification to let you know there is somthing to read, or the data is in the notification itself.

If the data is in the notification, get it from the GattValueChangedEventArgs in the Charac_ValueChanged event.
Else read it in the Charac_ValueChanged.

The data you receive is in the format of IBuffer. To convert IBuffer to string I will show in the code example.
Add using Windows.Security.Cryptographyto your code.

The code example compiles OK, but don't expect it to work "out of the box", I cannot see the rest of your code and have no acces to the Ble-device.
Use the debugger and set breakpoints to inspect the code.

```
 static GattCharacteristic charac = null;

  public static async Task connectToAddress()
  {
     Guid guid = new Guid("6e400001b5a3f393e0a9e50e24dcca9e"); // Base UUID for UART service
     Guid charachID = new Guid("6e400003b5a3f393e0a9e50e24dcca9e"); // RX characteristic UUID

     deviceReference = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(_deviceAddress);
     GattDeviceServicesResult result = await deviceReference.GetGattServicesAsync();
     //Allways check result!
     if (result.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
     {
        //Put following two lines in try/catch to or check for null!!
        var characs = await result.Services.Single(s => s.Uuid == guid).GetCharacteristicsAsync();
        //Make charac a field so you can use it in Charac_ValueChanged.
         charac = characs.Characteristics.Single(c => c.Uuid == charachID);
        GattCharacteristicProperties properties = charac.CharacteristicProperties;
        if (properties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Read))
        {
           Debug.Write("This characteristic supports reading from it.");
        }
        if (properties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Write))
        {
           Debug.Write("This characteristic supports writing.");
        }
        if (properties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Notify))
        {
           Debug.Write("This characteristic supports subscribing to notifications.");
        }
        try
        {
           //Write the CCCD in order for server to send notifications.               
           var notifyResult = await charac.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(
                                                     GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);
           if (notifyResult == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
           {

              Debug.Write("Successfully registered for notifications");
           }
           else
           {
              Debug.Write($"Error registering for notifications: {notifyResult}");
           }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
           Debug.Write(ex.Message);
        }


        charac.ValueChanged += Charac_ValueChangedAsync; ;
     }
     else
     {
        Debug.Write("No services found");
     }
  }

  private static async void Charac_ValueChangedAsync(GattCharacteristic sender, GattValueChangedEventArgs args)
  {
     CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(args.CharacteristicValue, out byte[] data);
     string dataFromNotify;
     try
     {
        //Asuming Encoding is in ASCII, can be UTF8 or other!
        dataFromNotify = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
        Debug.Write(dataFromNotify);
     }
     catch (ArgumentException)
     {
        Debug.Write("Unknown format");
     }
     GattReadResult dataFromRead = await charac.ReadValueAsync();        
     CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(dataFromRead.Value, out byte[] dataRead);
     string dataFromReadResult;
     try
     {
        //Asuming Encoding is in ASCII, can be UTF8 or other!
        dataFromReadResult = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataRead);
        Debug.Write("DATA FROM READ: " + dataFromReadResult);
     }
     catch (ArgumentException)
     {
        Debug.Write("Unknown format");
     }
  }
```

There is also no need to make your methods  STATIC. I left dat as it was, so it is easier to compare it with you code.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much for this response. I tried the code you gave but i get in console "Error registering for notifications: Unreachable". This is the same response i get from the Bluetooth LE Explorer windows app when i try to connect my module. Maybe is my device the problem? Do i need some special permissions to connect to it? The Bluefruit LE i am using uses the nRF51822 chip and i am trying to connect from a BT-400 dongle. Even if i can't subscribe to notifications i still can see the services and characteristics.

Comment: In your app's Package.appxmanifest you have to set capabilities to Bluetooth.
The easy way to do this in visual studio is to rightclick your project in solution explorer and select properties.
in Application section click package manifest and select capabilities tab and select Bluetooth.
If this is not the solution than you configured you Adafruit Bluefruit UART Friend wrong.
Go true the Adafruit instruction again to set it up as UART Service.

Comment: I reconfigured my Bluefruit and used the datamode sketch on my arduino. Now everything works perfect. Thank you very much for your answers, you helped me a lot!